# Checking for getrandom() function returns no when building Python 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.5

I'm trying to build Python 3.5.1 on a GCE Ubuntu 14.04 VM and when running ./configure inside the unzipped folder I get:

```
checking for the Linux getrandom() syscall... no
checking for the getrandom() function... no
```

The `uname -a` command returns:

`Linux server.mydomain.com 3.19.0-58-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:05:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I don't why configure cannot detect getrandom(), on the Python 3.5.1 release documentation it says Python interpreter [will detect and use this function/system call in Linux Kernels above 3.17](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#os)

What am I missing here? Anyone had the same issue?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Danilo

Comment: have you installed `python-dev` and `build-essential`?

Comment: Yes, all installed and the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test program Python uses to determine whether you have `getrandom()` is here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/4491bdb6527b/#l3.176

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main() {
    const int flags = 0;
    char buffer[1];
    int n;
    /* ignore the result, Python checks for ENOSYS at runtime */
    (void)syscall(SYS_getrandom, buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags);
    return 0;
}
```

What do you get if you try to build that program on your system?  If it works, your Python should use `getrandom()`, otherwise you should see from the compiler output what the problem is.

Edit: Now that we see that indeed you do not have `SYS_getrandom`, we can say for certain what the problem is: your kernel is new enough to support `getrandom()`, but your `libc` is not.  The solution is to upgrade your `glibc-dev`.

Comment: I get `test_get_random.c:8:19: error: ‘SYS_getrandom’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     (void)syscall(SYS_getrandom, buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags);`
Looking for it online gave me no clues why the constant is missing on my sys call.h

Comment: @DaniloRiecken: I've appended more detail to my answer.  You need a newer glibc.

Comment: @JohnZwinck : how to install a newver glibc?

Comment: @realtebo: Just Google the question you have just asked me.